# OSError at /admin/pages/richtextpage/3/ [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'

Tags: python, django, django-admin, mezzanine, django-static

I am creating pages from admin in mezzanine and in description of page I want to show some images but when I am giving the images path and trying to save it , the page is throwing this error.

```
OSError at /admin/pages/richtextpage/3/

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'
```

As I am using mezzanine so i haven't edit settings file for static root or url .
The settings are as follows :

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))
```

However in front end everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

This error are thrown because your web server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) haven't permission to write in `/your_project/static/` directory. You need find out from what user web server process run and set permissions for this user to static directory.

Comment: But if the same thing is working fine at front end then why not admin ? because the server is same at both front and backend .

Comment: Maybe you upload files in admin only? Or when you work with "front end" files uploaded in different place - /media/ directory.

Comment: so you need watch what permissions are set to "media" and set same permissions to "static" directory